# Is there any way to mock private static method with mockery?

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit, mockery

Take for example I have a class `SampleService` like following, now how can I write unit test with PHPUnit for the `getName()` method? more specifically how can i mock `self::_getName();` with Mockery? If that is not possible, what are the best approach/way to write unit test for this kinds of scenarios? Thanks.

```php
class SampleService implements Service
{    
    public function getName(){
        $name = self::_getName();
        return 'Mr. '.$name;
    }

    private static function _getName(){
        return 'Some Name';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, and you should not use them in TDD. Use them only if you shall never need to mock it.

And if you need to mock it - move all the code into a new class and mock the new class.